# Multiple python loops in same process

Tags: python, loops, multiprocessing, tk-toolkit

I have a project that I'm writing in Python that will be sending hardware (Phidgets) commands.  Because I'll be interfacing with more than one hardware component, I need to have more than one loop running concurrently.

I've researched the Python `multiprocessing` module, but it turns out that the hardware can only be controlled by one process at a time, so all my loops need to run in the same process.

As of right now, I've been able to accomplish my task with a `Tk()` loop, but without actually using any of the GUI tools.  For example:

```
from Tk import tk

class hardwareCommand:
    def __init__(self):
        # Define Tk object
        self.root = tk()

        # open the hardware, set up self. variables, call the other functions
        self.hardwareLoop()
        self.UDPListenLoop()
        self.eventListenLoop()

        # start the Tk loop
        self.root.mainloop()


    def hardwareLoop(self):
        # Timed processing with the hardware
        setHardwareState(self.state)
        self.root.after(100,self.hardwareLoop)


    def UDPListenLoop(self):
        # Listen for commands from UDP, call appropriate functions
        self.state = updateState(self.state)
        self.root.after(2000,self.UDPListenLoop)


    def eventListenLoop(self,event):
        if event == importantEvent:
            self.state = updateState(self.event.state)
        self.root.after(2000,self.eventListenLoop)

hardwareCommand()
```

So basically, the only reason for defining the `Tk()` loop is so that I can call the `root.after()` command within those functions that need to be concurrently looped.

This works, but is there a better / more pythonic way of doing it?  I'm also wondering if this method causes unnecessary computational overhead (I'm not a computer science guy).

Thanks!

Comment: loop in daemon thread

Comment: Perhaps consider taking a look at [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/)

Comment: Have you looked at python threading (not multiprocess?)  Things like locks and threads allow you to manage multiple threads and coordinate their access to particular pieces of hardware, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The multiprocessing module is geared towards having multiple separate processes. Although you can use `Tk`'s event loop, that is unnecessary if you don't have a Tk based GUI, so if you just want multiple tasks to execute in the same process you can use the `Thread` module. With it you can create specific classes which encapsulate a separate thread of execution, so you can have many "loops" executing simultaneously in the background. Think of something like this:

```
from threading import Thread

class hardwareTasks(Thread):

    def hardwareSpecificFunction(self):
        """
        Example hardware specific task
        """
        #do something useful
        return

    def run(self):
        """
        Loop running hardware tasks
        """
        while True:
            #do something
            hardwareSpecificTask()


class eventListen(Thread):

    def eventHandlingSpecificFunction(self):
        """
        Example event handling specific task
        """
        #do something useful
        return

    def run(self):
        """
        Loop treating events
        """
        while True:
            #do something
            eventHandlingSpecificFunction()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Instantiate specific classes
    hw_tasks = hardwareTasks()
    event_tasks = eventListen()

    # This will start each specific loop in the background (the 'run' method)
    hw_tasks.start()
    event_tasks.start()

    while True:
        #do something (main loop)
```

You should check [this article](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/) to get more familiar with the `threading` module. Its [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#) is a good read too, so you can explore its full potential.